# My app icon looks rounded, not adaptive. Android

Tags: android

I want to make my app icon adaptive for all sizes. But it shows circular in a square. I did res -> new image asset, and create it. Preview is correct, but in app, it is not.

new image asset, preview is correct:
[image: new image asset, preview is correct]

incorrect icon in my phone and emulator:

[image: incorrect icon in my phone and emulator]

**Manifest**

```
android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_v4"
```

**mipmap/app_icon_v4.xml(anydpi-v26)**

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<background android:drawable="@color/app_icon_v4_background"/>
<foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/app_icon_v4_foreground"/>
```

Also there are app_icon_v4_foreground pngs for different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you really have all the files generated. I had an issue with my icon not being adaptive when generating icons on Linux.

What I found is that when I create the icons, only the PNG files exist. Then when I generated the icons again, only the XMLs were in the folders. This would repeat indefinitely, never ending up with all the files generated at once.

I solved this by generating the icon, copying the files outside of the Android Studio project, and then generating the icon again. Then I just copied the files back to have a complete set of icon files.